# FastAPI Custom Error Handling Broke Automatic Documentation

Tags: python, microservices, fastapi

**For our requirements, I made the following changes**

- I updated the input validation exception code from 422 to 400.
- I also modified the default Json error output.

**My issue**

My FastAPI generated automatic documentation is sill showing default error code and error message format.

**My Question**

Is it possible to update the API documentation to reflect my change like the correct error code and the right error output format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Currently](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1376) there is no simple way. You have to modify the *OpenAPI* file as described [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/#modify-the-openapi-schema). Meaning you have to load the dictionary and remove the references to the error 422. Here is a minimal example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.openapi.utils import get_openapi
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items():
    return [{"name": "Foo"}]


@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request, exc):
    """Your custom validation exception."""
    message = 
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=400,
        content={"message": f"Validation error: {exc}"}
    )


def custom_openapi():
    if app.openapi_schema:
        return app.openapi_schema
    openapi_schema = get_openapi()

    # look for the error 422 and removes it
    for method in openapi_schema["paths"]:
        try:
            del openapi_schema["paths"][method]["post"]["responses"]["422"]
        except KeyError:
            pass

    app.openapi_schema = openapi_schema
    return app.openapi_schema


app.openapi = custom_openapi
```

Answer (score 0):

The current way to do it is modifying the generated OpenAPI https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/